Суммирование значений из разных листов
У меня есть таблица в "Гугл таблицы". На ней несколько листов. На кадом таком листе, есть диапазон с числами, выстраенные в колонку. Как мне суммировать каждое первое число из первого листа, с каждым первым числом из последующих листов? Условно "Лист1" колонка "А1" строка 1 + "Лист2" колонка "А1" строка 1 + "Лист3" колонка "А1" строка 1 + ..., а после так же суммировать "Лист1" колонка "А1" строка 2 + "Лист2" колонка "А1" строка 2 + "Лист3" колонка "А1" строка 2 + ...
Я перебрал практически все, что я знаю, варианты. но он мне суммирует все числа со всех листов. Прошу, подскажите. Мучаюсь с этим уже неделю.
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = sheet.getSheets();
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < activeSheet.length; i++) {
        var list = activeSheet[i];
        var range = list.getRange('A1:A10');
        var value = range.getValues();
        for(var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
            if(value[j][0] !== "") { 
                sum += value[j][0];
                Logger.log(sum);
            }
        }
}


вам обязательно это скриптом делать? можно же простой формулой обойтись

"Лист1" строка "А1" строка 2  - что такое строка "А1" строка 2? A1 - это адрес ячейки, а не строки. Можно поточнее задачу описать?

Небольшое дополнение к вашему коду - собираем суммы в объект (словарь), где ключи - индексы ячейки 0..n внутри диапазона, а значения - суммы значений ячеек с этими индексами.
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = sheet.getSheets();
    
    var sum = {}
    for(var i = 0; i < activeSheet.length; i++) {
        var list = activeSheet[i];
        var range = list.getRange('A1:A10');
        var value = range.getValues();
        for(var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
            if(value[j][0] !== "") { 
                if (sum[j]===undefined) sum[j]=value[j][0]
                  else
                sum[j] += value[j][0]
            }
        }
  }
  sum = Object.values(sum)
  Logger.log(sum);
}

Данные на листах

Массив value выглядит так: [[10], [20], [],[]] - это значения с первого листа; [[30],[40],[],[]] - значения второго, [[50],[60],[],[]] - значения третьего и т.д.

Результат
18:27:59    Примечание  Выполнение начато
18:27:59    Информация  [90.0, 120.0]
18:28:00    Примечание  Выполнение завершено


Спасибо вам огромное! Всё работает! Идея с объектом просто класс!
Единственное, что ещё у вас спрошу, можно ли как-то не учитывать отрицательные значения? Чтобы они не суммировались, если такие на одном из листе имеются...

Сделал сам.
Добавил в условие && value[j][0] > 0
Лучше, скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы не учитывались "скрытые" листы?

Очевидно, нужно проверить возвращаемое методом .isSheetHidden() значение

Еще раз, большое вам спасибо!

Алексей, подскажите пожалуйста. Я поменял диапазон в var range = list.getRange('A1:A10'); с 'A1:A10' на var range = list.getRange(i, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1);, хочу, чтобы скрипт суммировал диапазон последнего столбца и начинал с шестой строки (выше находится шапка). Но он почему-то начинает суммировать с 10 строки... Не понимаю почему...

Для начала проверьте, какой все-таки диапазон у вас в range, например, методом .getA1Notation()

Получилось сделать самому.
// Получаем все данные с листа     var range = list.getDataRange();  // Получаем количество строк и столбцов       var rangeRows = range.getNumRows()        var rangeColumns = range.getNumColumns(); // Индекс последнего столбца       var lastColumnIndex = rangeColumns;   // Получаем диапазон последнего столбца           var lastColumnRange = list.getRange(6, lastColumnIndex - 1, rangeRows); // Значения с последнего столбца       var value = lastColumnRange.getValues();

Алексей, извините за частые вопросы, этот будет последний, не хочу создавать новый вопрос...
Мне нужно прописать условие, при котором: если сумма всех чисел из строки превышает или равно  "97", то в ячейке рядом писать: "Ошибка". Я перепробовал несколько вариантов, но внутри цикла это не работает, а за его приделами приходиться создавать новый. Может быть у вас есть более простое решение...

Пропущена одна закрывающая скобка.
Обратите внимание на то, что лежит в value. Там массив из одной колонки. Задавать выбор из него двумя символами не нужно. Оставьте только j.
Также данные собраны с типом строка, нужно чтобы было число.
Порядок перебора i и j перепутаны, если вы хотите, чтобы сначала складывались первые числа всех листов, потом вторые и т.д., то нужно перебор по ячейкам вывести выше, чем перебор по листам (или, другими словами, вложить перебор листов внутрь перебора по ячейкам).
И последнее, не обязательно, но чуть удобнее: отдельно value выводить не обязательно, можно было сразу getValues() вписать после getRange('A1:A10').
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = sheet.getSheets();
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < activeSheet.length; i++) {
        var list = activeSheet[i];
        var range = list.getRange('A1:A10');
        var value = range.getValues();
        for(var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
            if(value[j] !== "") { 
                sum += Number(value[j]);
                Logger.log(sum);
            }
        }
    }
}


Добрый день. Массив value выглядит так: [[10], [20], [],[]] - это значения с первого листа; [[30],[40],[],[]] - значения второго, [[50],[60],[],[]] - значения третьего и т.д. Как мне суммировать 10 + 30 + 50, а потом 30 + 40 + 60. Код выше работает так же. Он берет все эти числа и суммирует.

К сожалению, ваш код суммирует все числа подряд, тогда как задача требует суммирования по строкам. Попробуйте немного изменить код [edit] так, чтобы значения суммировались построчно (--->то есть значения одной строки всех листов). Это сделает решение более точным
